# Sylius(Symfony) overwriting templates

Tags: symfony, twig, sylius

I want to overwrite template called `productIndex.html.twig` which lives in `vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle/Resources/views/Backend/ProductArchetype/productIndex.html.twig`. So I copy this file to `app/Resources/SyliusWebBundle/views/Backend/ProductArchetype/productIndex.html.twig` like Symfony [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates) said and modyfing it. But Symfony still renders this one from `vendor`. I use `Sylius v0.17.0 standard edtion` How I can fix it?

Comment: Might seem obvious, but did you clear the cache?

Answer (score 0):

For Sylius, you need to first override `Resource` configuration to your own bundle then override routing which point to your own template.

`sylius.yml`

```
sylius_variation:
    classes:
        product:
            variant:
                controller: MyApp\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller\VariantController
```

---

`src/MyApp/Bundle/WebBundle/Resources/views/Backend/ProductVariant/index.html.twig`

```
{% extends 'SyliusWebBundle:Backend:layout.html.twig' %}

{% from 'SyliusWebBundle:Backend/Macros:misc.html.twig' import pagination %}
{% from 'SyliusWebBundle:Backend/ProductVariant:macros.html.twig' import list_all %}
{% import 'SyliusResourceBundle:Macros:buttons.html.twig' as buttons %}

{# Do whatever you want #}
```